# TMS format specification

Tags: gdal, c++, tile-map-service

I want to convert large map file to tms format i.e. how directory structure, zoom levels , tile size, xml file creation have to be dealt with.

Can you point to the relevant docs?

And is there any gdal c++ api to create tiles(not gdal2tiles.py)?

Answer (score 1):

TMS was an unofficial, interim standard created by OSGeo:

http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification

A counterpart was accepted by the OGC standards-creating body as 'Web Map Tile Service'.  The WMTS standard is available here:

http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts

GDAL distributes GDAL2Tiles bundled in with the library as an official utility, and a GUI tool was put out by the creators, MapTiler, to use it.  Maptiler comes in a free basic open-source version.  Later the developer created a paid 'cluster' version, presumably on a different codebase:
http://www.maptiler.org/

Aside from that, all these can be work with TMS/WMTS if you're willing to do some legwork (like setting up a WMS tileservice first):

http://mapproxy.org/

http://tilecache.org/

http://geowebcache.org/